# What are typical 'programming' sources of vulnerability to SQL injection exploit?

Tags: sql

Im trying to understand more about SQL injection, I know how it works and how to protect against it, but I just have a few questions.

- What are typical 'programming' sources of vulnerability to SQL injection exploit?
- What are typical 'system' and coding mechanisms that can be used to protect against SQL injection?

I would appreciate straight answers not links as I dont find them useful.

Thank you

Comment: It may help if you actually spell out what you already know.

Comment: If you know how it works and how to protect against it, why ask how it works and what can be used to protect against it?

Comment: If you go to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) you'd see an entire web site dedicated to explaining this issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Sources**:

- Not validating your input types.
- Concatenating Strings with inputs directly.
- Not using PreparedStatements to guarantee that only one instruction is executed.

**Solutions**:

- Use prepared statements.
- Validate input types (may be redundant if above point is used correctly).

Comment: Thank you a structive answer